# If $ x^2+x+1=0$ find the value of $8x^{282}+1799x^{183}+87x^{51}+124x^{-3}+1$

Tags: polynomials, roots

If$$ x^2+x+1=0$$ find the value of $$8x^{282}+1799x^{183}+87x^{51}+124x^{-3}+1$$

Solving this equation gives imaginary solutions.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Try use algorithm of division (long division).

Comment: **Hint** $\ \color{#c00}{x^3 = 1}\, $ and all its powers have form $\, x^{3N} =(\color{#c00}{x^3})^N = \color{#c00}{1}^N = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that such a $\;x\;$ fufills $\;x^3=1\;$ ...

Comment: Oh ... ! Yes ! Thank you sir

Answer (score 3):

With $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ we can use $x^{3}=1$ and then reduce the polynomial to $f(x)=8+1799+87+124+1=2019$. This is almost $3$ years ahead, though.